# Jquery Show & ScrollTop (or ScrollTo)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just as the topic says I'm trying to get a link to open a hidden div then scroll to it. I have the first part taken care of. As for the scrollTop or ScrollTo function I've been trying to use the ScrollTo plugin and for an unknown reason it's not working.

First of all does this look correct?

```
<li>
    <a href="#" rel="toggle[kov]" title="$.scrollTo('div#kov', 500);">
        Sara Kovanda
    </a>
```

Then later down the page

```
<section class="container" id="kov">
```

I'm using the dynamic drive script, http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/animatedcollapse.htm
For the first part since after hours of looking I cannot find a jquery plugin that allows for multiple divs that show on click and hides any current div that's open.

Any help would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: Any more(preferably all) of your code would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: My site is still being developed but I'll just share the link to the relevant page.
http://chpmn.com/work/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple example, no plugins:

http://jsfiddle.net/wr2sj/2/

```
$("#a").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#b").offset().top
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I followed your link and although it does show a div it failed to scroll to it.

What I'm aiming for here is to have multiple links, each one opens a unique div then once open it scrolls to it.

Comment: I didn't come here hoping someone would write it all for me, but this is exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for your time, much <3