# Is it possible to combine jQuery effects .show() with .scrollTop()?

Tags: jquery

### Below is the code I'd like to combine. (I'm doing this in Wordpress)

#### Html

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
    <div id="extra-gallery" style="display:none">
    <h2 class="extra-gallery-title">Image Gallery</h2>

     (My Gallery loop)

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

#### jQuery I'd like to combine

*This*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery("#hide").click(function(){
    jQuery("#extra-gallery").hide();
  });
  jQuery("#show").click(function(){
    jQuery("#extra-gallery").show( 700 );
  });
});
```

*And this*

```
jQuery("#show").click(function() {
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#hide").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

#### Expected result

The page scrolls to the #hide button at the bottom of my gallery or scrolls so that the gallery is in the centre of the page, when the #show button is clicked.

#### So Far

I started using jQuery yesterday. I've read through the Api documentation for .hide(), .show() and scrollTop and also played around with examples on w3schools. There have been some close example answers on this site which have jsfiddle examples set-up.
At the moment I can't transfer the examples to my particular situation.

I have the show and hide working well. Animating the page scroll to the shown content would finish this page off nicely. Any help would be really appreciated, directs to more reading is welcomed too.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: This is not the place where you assign us work and we do it for you. This place is rather different where you can clarify your doubts and proceed on your own.

Comment: Not asking for work to be done for me. Thanks any way. Just thought some one with more experience would be able to point me in the right direction. Such as, further reading? I only ask "how to combine .show() and .scrolltop()"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kei and a simple code snippet accompanied by a jsfiddle in the question below, I was able to tweak and learn more about what to do to solve my question.

[Jquery Show & ScrollTop (or ScrollTo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473901/jquery-show-scrolltop-or-scrollto?rq=1)

Here's the working code I used on my wordpress site and here's the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/earthling/Eu77V/1/

### Html

```
<button id="show">Show</button>
    <div id="extra-gallery" style="display:none">
    <h2 class="extra-gallery-title">Image Gallery</h2>

     (My Gallery loop)

<button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#extra-gallery").fadeIn(2000); 
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#hide").offset().top
        }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $('#extra-gallery').fadeOut();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Please remember if you want to use this that it's coded for Wordpress.